# Cordova Device plugin won't let me access the "device" properties

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

My cordova app uses `device.uuid` after I installed the `device` plugin, I still cannot use that property and my app hangs up on the line where I use device.uuid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS7 you can no longer use the `device.uuid` Apple made impossible to track devices. You will have to use either the advertising id, vendor ID or create your own unique ID.

Just to add on this, from the developers site of [PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid)

> The uuid for iOS is not unique for a device, but is unique per
>   application per install. This will change if you delete the app and
>   re-install, and possibly also when you upgrade your iOS version, or
>   even upgrade your app per version (as we've seen in iOS 5.1). Not a
>   reliable value.

Looks like PhoneGap/Cordova is using [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) which kan sometimes return nil and you will have to wait some time before calling it again. Apparently this is not implemented correctly in the cordova and causes the hang in your app.

Comment: Meaning in the index.js I cannot use device.uuid?

Comment: Yes, Apple has removed the [`uniqueIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) method of `UIDevice` which was called by the cordova `device.uuid` on iOS.

Comment: The `UDID` retrieved under iOS 7 is a random number, Apple removed this method in iOS 7 and it is no longer available due to privacy issues.

Comment: Double checking - is generating a unique number and using it to identify a device allowed by apple right ?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 7 apple removed the `uniqueIdentifier`, the `device.uuid` is phonegap specific and it isn't using `uniqueIdentifier` internally, so you can still use it.

To use `device.uuid` on phonegap 3.X.X you have to add the device plugin first like this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

It works because I've just tested it (on cordova 3.5.0). If you installed the plugin and it was hanging your app maybe there was some bug with your phonegap version or the plugin wasn't installed correctly.

The problem with the device.uuid is that is isn't the real device uuid, from phonegap doc

> iOS Quirk
>
> The uuid on iOS is not unique to a device, but varies for each
>   application, for each installation. It changes if you delete and
>   re-install the app, and possibly also when you upgrade iOS, or even
>   upgrade the app per version (apparent in iOS 5.1). The uuid is not a
>   reliable value.

The `device.uuid` isn't using `identifierForVendor` either, it's just a random identifier  persisted on the device, but if you want to get the real `identifierForVendor` I've created a plugin to get it.

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin